# What is Asynchronous behavior of setstate in eventhandler of react component?

Tags: reactjs

```
handleClick=()=>{ 
   setOne(1)
   setTwo(prevState=>{ return prevState+1})
   setTimeOut(() =>{ setThree(3) },0) 
}
```

If handleClick is called, why component renders 2 times, first 2 state updates are done at once and another one inside settimeout is done later, why ?? Why it can't render in one shot.

Answer (score 0):

### **The behaviour is due to [Reactjs's batching update](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous)**

This means that all `setState` inside an eventHandler/function is batching to update synchronously.

The `setThree(3)` updates later and not being batched is because the fact that it's inside another function scope (setTimeout's callback).